# Can you use both Annotation and YAML routing?

Tags: symfony, routes

I have some symfony code that is using annotation routing.  I need to make a change to the routes where the host is now gotten from a setting in parameters.yml.  I saw that this is possible if you define routes in routing.yaml: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html  So I was wondering if it were possible to use routes defined in annotations and routing.yaml at the same time, or if you can only do one or the other (so in other words, I will have to change all the routes in the bundle to be in routing.yaml instead)?  Though I'm guessing it's not recommended to do both, to keep the code clean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use both. In fact what is happening in Symfony standard edition is just importing main `routing.yml` in `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
```

And in this `routing.yml` you import your `Controllers` with `annotation` routing:

**routing.yml:**

```
your_annotation_route:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php"
    type: annotation
#########  you can use regular yml routing here ########
your_yaml_route:
    path:     /
    host:     m.example.com
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:mobileHomepage }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, but also you can configure the router in order to generate your desired urls.

Here is an example for sending emails from a console command:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html

On console commands there is no request or webserver configuration. So this is another clear method to set up routes programmatically.
I hope it will help you.