# Which type of routing configuration gets more precedence in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Suppose we have defined routing for a particular controller in both annotation and yaml, by doing so which type will get triggered first.

Comment: If you can share the code base that will be helpful to understand your problem .  As far as I know we have to define path of bundle routes to main routes.yml file so what ever you defined there it will take only that one.

Comment: Hopefully this link can be helpful  to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860091/can-you-use-both-annotation-and-yaml-routing

Comment: By declaring your annotation routes in routing.yml, the order is then sequential, as usual.